# Do node.js applications need a web.xml file or another type of deployment descriptor?

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, web.xml

I am new to node.js and I'm developing using webstorm. Curious if I will need to write a deployment descriptor like web.xml to deploy on Heroku.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can count for sure, no .xml files needed with Node, however there is package.json, where you can list all your dependency needs for your app, it should look like this

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

Heroku has a really nice tutorial of how to get your node.js app up and running in their service, follow up in this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

If you are interested in learning all the great things of NPM and package.json, here is the entry in the npm docs : https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html

Have fun!

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that a Procfile is also needed to deploy node.js apps to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by David, you need a package.json file in the root dirctory of your project.

I found that man page hard to read. (I learn better by seeing examples).  So one option is to go to npmjs.org, browse some of the projects, and look at *their* package.json files (likely on GitHub).  Pick a couple of popular "big name" modules to view a largish package.json, then try a couple of little obscure packages to see a very basic package.json.

Then go re-read the docs, a book or online material, and it should make sense.  Good luck.